# how to use distinct hive when it refers to another table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

so I miss the basic understanding of distinct.
What I am trying to do is get the distinct of azkey, bzkey, and ytr from multiple left-outer-joins.
The syntax looks like this:

```
SELECT
    substr(aa.keyy, 9, -9)                                     AS azkey
    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(bb.rfkey,'[^*]+',1,3)                      AS bzkey 
    , (NVL(ba, 0) + NVL(dmo, 0) + NVL(cmo, 0) + NVL(bally, 0)) AS ytr
FROM
    tabletableaa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 bb
        ON aa.keyy = bb.don_key
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table cc
        ON aa.key = cc.cc_key
           AND aa_anothercolumn = cc.anothercolumn
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 dd
        ON aa.key = dd.dd_key
```

What is the best practice to do this? What I have tried to far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       (substr(a.keyy,9,-9)) as azkey,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(distinct(b.rfkey),'[^*]+',1,3) as bzkey
       (NVL(ba,0)+NVL(dmo,0)+NVL(cmo,0)+NVL(bally,0)) as ytr
```

I got his message :

> distinct keywords in not support in the context hive

Example of what i have got & the desired results :

what i have got :

```
azkey  bzkey   ytr
100     cx     356
100     cx     null
101     tr     796
101     null   null
101     null   998
102     cd     453
103     df     224
104     kq     756
```

desired results :

```
azkey  bzkey   ytr
100     cx     356
101     tr     796
102     cd     453
103     df     224
104     kq     756
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: distinct in hive is really costly and not performant , please provide sample data  and desired output to see if there is a better way

Comment: please check it once more, i have delivered the example @GordonLinoff

Comment: please check it once more, i have delivered the example @eshirvana

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need NULLs in bzkey then consider replacing LEFT JOIN with bb with INNER JOIN. Or If you need LEFT JOIN, try filtering `WHERE bzkey is not null`
Also aggregate ytr using max() group by azkey, bzkey - it will remove duplicates and nulls:

```
SELECT
      substr(aa.keyy, 9, -9)                                   AS azkey
    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(bb.rfkey,'[^*]+',1,3)                      AS bzkey 
    , max((NVL(ba, 0) + NVL(dmo, 0) + NVL(cmo, 0) + NVL(bally, 0))) AS ytr
FROM
    tabletableaa
    INNER JOIN Table1 bb
        ON aa.keyy = bb.don_key
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table cc
        ON aa.key = cc.cc_key
           AND aa_anothercolumn = cc.anothercolumn
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 dd
        ON aa.key = dd.dd_key
GROUP BY substr(aa.keyy, 9, -9)
    , REGEXP_SUBSTR(bb.rfkey,'[^*]+',1,3)
```